# Python: Google API if loop

Tags: python, json, google-maps, postman

I'm checking Google API response:

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?'                 
params = {'location': '-38.30000000,176.15000000',                                   
          'radius': '5000',                                             
          'type': 'movie_theater',
          'key': 'MY_KEY'}                                                      
response = requests.get(url = url, params=params)       
# if response.status_code == 200:                                                   
response_data = response.json()                                                     

if 'results' in response_data:
    print ('There are results')
elif response_data['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
    print ('nothing')
```

If you search with Postman for that specific location:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-38.30000000,176.15000000&radius=5000&type=movie_theater&key=MY_KEY
```

there are no cinemas and Google API reports:

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [],
  "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

unfortunately my `if`, `elif` seems not working because it doesn't print `nothing`.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code to:

```
if len(response_data['results']) in response_data:
    print ('There are results')

elif response_data['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
    print ('nothing')
```

OR

Just change the order of the conditions:

```
if response_data['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
    print ('nothing')

elif 'results' in response_data:
    print ('There are results')
```

Answer (score 0):

But "results" *is* in the response data. It just contains an empty list.

One way of fixing this might be to swap the order of your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking for the existence of the result key in the response_data, which exists, so the "there are results" is correct. You might check for the len of reponse_data['results'] and in case of 0 length print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right, you need to check the length of the 'results' array.

Python falsifies empty arrays and **.get()** from dict will default to None so you can also simply do:

```
if response_data.get('results'):
    print ('yay! we have results')
```